# SQL left outer joins

Tags: sql, left-join, outer-join

So I have one table which has employee number `(empno)`, `name(ename)` and `manager number(mgr)`.
The question: List the names of all employees along with the name of their manager and the name of their manager's manager, with a blank at any left if a manager does not exist.

What I have so far:
 `SELECT a.ename, b.ename, b.mgr FROM emp a LEFT OUTER JOIN emp b ON a.mgr=b.empno`

This shows the employee, their manager, and their manager's number... Anyone able to help me change the manager number in the third column into a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already most of the way there, you want to do the same thing you did in your first join.

```
SELECT a.ename, 
       b.ename, 
       c.ename 
FROM emp a 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN emp b 
     ON a.mgr=b.empno;
 LEFT OUTER JOIN emp c
     ON b.mgr=c.empno
```

Note: I'd use a bit more friendly names for your aliases. a, b, c are pretty confusing.